# Gitlab-ci transform only to rules with unknown synthax

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I have to update the synthax on our .gitlab-ci.yml from `only` synthax to `rules`. I did the majority of the changes, but I cannot find information on the following synthax :

```
deploy-image:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - stage@helloTeam/Expansion
```

`helloTeam/Expansion` is the name of our repository, but I don't know what the `stage@` is for. And how to convert it with rules. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in [only/except examples](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#onlyrefs--exceptrefs-examples) for job control.

> The `@` symbol denotes the beginning of a ref’s repository path

And one example of its usage:

> To execute jobs only for the parent repository and not forks:

```
job:
  only:
    - branches@gitlab-org/gitlab
  except:
    - main@gitlab-org/gitlab
    - /^release/.*$/@gitlab-org/gitlab
```

So, `foo@bar/baz` in `only:` means `foo` is a ref (branch name or [special keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyrefs--exceptrefs)) and `bar/baz` is a repository path.

The following `rules:` could be used as an equivalent to this using the [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` and `CI_PROJECT_PATH`:

```yaml
rules:
  - if: $CI_PROJECT_PATH == "bar/baz" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "foo"
```

Comment: `CI_PROJECT_PATH` is the variable I was looking for. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found that target the branch `stage` on non forked repository.

More details about the `only:refs / except:refs` **keywords** can be found [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#onlyrefs--exceptrefs-examples). And for the `refs` possible values/inputs, check this [link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#onlyrefs--exceptrefs).

So,
the equivalent with rules is :

```yaml
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE == "helloTeam" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "stage"'
```

Curious if it's possible to target the whole name, `helloTeam/Expansion` instead of just `helloTeam`.